# Allow read/write access to a folder in the /var folder

Tags: permissions, chmod

Bonsoir à, s'il vous plait je débute sous Ubuntu et pour terminer l'installation du logiciel testlink sur Ubuntu je dois dois créer un certain dossier dans la racine /var/testlink.
Mais en voulant donner les droits d'accès en lecture et écriture au dit dossier ça met plutôt une croix dessus.
J'ai essayé la commande: sudo chmod -r 777 /var/testlink (sans succès).
Svp quelqu'un saurait comment remédier à celà ??

---

In order to complete the installation of the testlink software on Ubuntu I have to create a new folder in the root `/var/testlink`, but when I'm trying to give read and write access rights to this folder, it rather puts a cross on it. I unsuccessfully tried the command: `sudo chmod -r 777 /var/testlink`.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If you peruse the manpage for chmod, you will see that `-r` might have done something different than you intended.

Comment: Bonsoir, et bienvenue à Ask Ubuntu! Mais, ce site est anglophone exclusivement. Vous devez traduire votre question, ou vous pourriez poster sur le forum [ubuntu-fr.org](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Files in the root has as autor root, so before doing any change of rights we have to put the user as autor
With the command: chown -R $user_name name_directory.